# Client.getConversationByUniqueName and Client.getConversationBySid cannot find conversations created by other users

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

Note: I'm using @twilio/conversations version 1.1.0 in node project. I'm transitioning from using Programmable Chat to Conversations.

I'm seeing calls to `Client.getConversationByUniqueName` and `Client.getConversationBySid` are not returning existing channels that were created by other users.

Example:

User 'A' (with its own unique identity and token) successfully created conversation 'myConvo1'using the following code:

```
client.createConversation({
   uniqueName: 'myConvo1',
   friendlyName: 'myConvo1',
 });
```

User 'B' (with its own unique identity and token) cannot find that conversation using: `Client.getConversationByUniqueName('myConvo1')` OR `Client.getConversationBySid(sid)` (just passing in the sid I get from the initial createConversation call).
 
I see these errors respectively:

```
Not Found    at ​​​Upstream.actualSend​​​
      ​./node_modules/@twilio/conversations/node_modules/twilsock/lib/services/upstream.js:135

Conversation with SID CHc4565e40a32f4bffaf490bae2cff45db is not found. 
      at ​​​conversations.syncListRead.promise.then.then.conversation​​​ ​./node_modules/@twilio/conversations/lib/client.js:283
```

However, I can access this conversation fine with the same functions if I'm using User A's token/identity.
Also, when I call this from User B's Client:

```
client.createConversation({
       uniqueName: 'myConvo1',
       friendlyName: 'myConvo1',
     });
```

I get this error: `Conversation with provided unique name already exists`. So all of this leads me to believe the conversation is out there, but it's just not available for other users to join.

Note 2: I've been referencing the docs below. I don't see any explicit examples on how to find and join channels, so I may be missing something or approaching this wrong.

https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/1.1.0/docs/Client.html

https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations

Answer (score 2):

Could this be the reason, where Twilio Conversations only supports private channels, not public channels like Programmable Chat?

[Public vs. Private Channel Use Cases with Twilio Programmable Chat](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005970527-Public-vs-Private-Channel-Use-Cases-with-Twilio-Programmable-Chat)

[Migrating to Conversations from Programmable Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/migrating-chat-conversations#all-conversations-are-private)

Comment: Yes. Conversations are private. I was missing the fact that participants need to be invited/added (i.e. conversation.add('user123') by someone already in the chat.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi  @mwest-cs from where I can get conversation  variable if I want to use add method as you explained : conversation.add('user123')

Answer (score 0):

I created multiple Service ID's and using one specific(XXXX-Chat-Dev) Chat Service ID, but application took the Default Chat Service ID which I didn't mentioned in backend.

Fixed by deleting the Default Chat Service ID in Twilio.

[image: Chat Service ID]

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As @mwest-cs mentioned, the issue was that participants have to be added after creating conversation. I've created conversations on backend, so that they were created by `system`, not by one of participants. It's ok, just need to add all participants to the conversation. That's the code I got working for me eventually:

```js
const Twilio = require('twilio');

const conversationUserIds = [123, 456]; // TODO: replace with real ones; those are my custom user IDs, not Twilio User SIDs.

const twilioClient = Twilio(twilioConfig.ACCOUNT_SID, twilioConfig.AUTH_TOKEN);
const newConversation = await twilioClient.conversations.conversations.create({ uniqueName });
await Promise.all(conversationUserIds.map((userId) =>
    channel.participants().create({ identity: userId })
));
```

Please note, that as per the [Twilio Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-participant-resource), creating a Participant joins them with the conversation, and the connected person will receive all subsequent messages.

Also, you can check how many participants in your conversation by going to [Expore Products in Twilio Console](https://console.twilio.com/develop/explore) -> Conversations, on the left sidebar: Conversations -> Manage -> Services, choose the service, then on the left sidebar: Conversation (in the bottom). Here you can see the table of all your conversations, and there is table column Participants indication participant count in each conversation.

Happy coding!